# Can any character weave a thread to any item?

Tags: earthdawn-1e

So, I know there are minor, major and wondrous items.
I also know that some magical items are made, and some other just happen to become magical after they become significant.

I know you need to know the knowledges and do the deeds to weave a thread to any item.

I know you need the legend points, and that you can only weave a number of threads equal to your threadwaving.

What I don't know is: **can any character weave a thread to any item?** Could a wizard link to an axe? Would it have all the powers (if any at all) since wizardry is not "war weaving" or "axe weaving"? Can an archer weave thread to anything else than bows?

If you can weave to anything, why bother to name all the weaving differently (except for flavor)?
If you can't weave anything not clearly in your weaving talent's range, how could one link to a ring (since rings are clearly not made for combat/any discipline in mind)?

While searching for clues around this question, I found a quote that implies that there is a difference (unless it's only different for the spellcaster's weaving): *"Using the versatility talent, human characters may purchase ranks in thread weaving talents other than those listed for their discipline."* (*Earthdawn* 1st edition, p. 118)

I'm playing First Edition, but failing an answer for that, I'm using Third and Classic as references so answers for those are useful if no answer for First can be found.

Comment: It's kind of baffling that nobody ever wondered about that. It's so unclear.

Comment: Where is the new quote from (book + page)?

Comment: Earthdawn core p.118 under Thread Weaving.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Experienced DM going back to 1st here. The quote about Versatility mainly applies to Spellcaster-type Threadweaving talents, so a Human caster can pick up out-of-Discipline spells.

To answer the main question, yes. Any type of Threadweaving allows you to attach threads to Named items. The limits are # of threads active & max rank of each = threadwaving talent rank. Any Talent/Power granted that is not part of the weaver's Discipline is granted at a base Rank equal to the bonus given. For example, if a Wizard finds a pair of Named Boots that grant +2 Air Dance (a Warrior talent) once his thread is at rank 2 and would be able to tap the Talent at Rank 2, talent step at Dex(+2). A Warrior with the Talent already at rank 3 would now have a total talent step of Dex+3(+2).

Sometimes the system wants you to look up your Talent Rank, or the total Talent Step (base Rank + Attribute Step + any enchantments), so the distinction can be important. In 1st edition days, I think this was clarified on the FASA mailing list Q&A.

Comment: so, an human weaponsmith would have nothing to gain by versatilizing ArrowWeaving, right? Thanks for the answer, it's been nagging me for quite a while :)

Comment: Correct. Outside of Spellcasting mechanincs, all Threadweaving sub-types function the same mechanically. The sub-type for non-casters is mainly an additional point where the mechanics and world metaphysics contact each other (you'll notice Earthdawn does this a LOT). This mainly comes into focus when roleplaying the scenes where the adept is investigating and tying threads to items.